# Slow Windows Application Startup

Tags: windows, performance, java, jdk, jvm

I have Windows 8 Pro/i5 3320M laptop with 8GB memory. Java based applications such as Eclipse, Phpstorm takes about 15-30 mins to load. (i assume issue is with java apps, others work fine).

I tried disk defragmenting, reinstalling JVM/JDK (8u20 x64), reinstalling applications, clean with CCleaner. But still issue exists.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough memory for your mix of applications?  You could be swapping badly.  Have you checked the resource monitor for more infomation?

Comment: @mdpc ya, this happen when fresh start also, without opening other apps. CPU usage seems high anyway.